ModuleNotFoundError while importing from submodule in jenkins run
I'm trying to run some python scripts in a jenkins pipeline environment.
The repository structure set in a way that there are some python scripts that are needed for the main scrips' running, but are sourced out in a git submodule within the same git group as the main repository.
The structure looks like this:
|root|
     |app|
         __init__.py <- where the import happens
     |submodule_parent_folder|  <- submodule

At the start of the pipeline, in a preparation stage the workspace, these repos get cloned via:
'git clone && git submodule update --init --recursive'.
When trying to run a script that would use the import, I get a :
app/__init__.py:2: in <module>
  import submodule_parent_folder
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'submodule_parent_folder'

The init.py itself looks like this:
try:
  import submodule_parent_folder
except Exception as e:
  raise Exception('Please update submodule_parent_folder: git submodule update --init --recursive')

Checked file system integrity and also python module import schemas in the pipeline container, everything is in place as should.
Same scripts with the same file structure work perfectly both on local machine and in VMs.
